# clustering similar words and then mapping clusters into numbers in python

Tags: python, mapping, cluster-analysis, similarity

I'm familiar with k-means to cluster data points, but not text.. So I have one column of words( some rows has only one word and some have more etc.)  in cvs format, which I want to cluster those which have similar word or more, and then mapping those cluster to numbers as index, those index numbers needed to be added as a second column. I know there is scipy packahes and word2vec in python, but this is the first time for me dealing with clustering text.. Any idea on how to do this?? Any code examples will be appreciated

Edit:What I want are not the similar words in meaning, I want the similar like the exact text, for example: we have three words in different three rows: Heart attack , Heart failure, Heart broken.. for example .. I want those rows to be in one cluster cause they have the common word " Heart... And by the way, all the rows are connected with each other somehow, so what I really want is to cluster the exact words

```
from csv import DictReader
import sets



### converting my cvs file into list!!
with open("export.csv") as f:
   my_list = [row["BASE_NAME"] for row in DictReader(f)]


#print(my_list)  
## having every word in the cvs file
Set = list()   
for item in my_list:

      MySet = list(set(item.split(' ')))
      Set.append(MySet)

#print(Set)
cleanlist = []
[cleanlist.append(x) for x in Set if x not in cleanlist]
print(cleanlist[1])
#print(cleanlist)

###my_list = ['abc-123', 'def-456', 'ghi-789', 'abc-456']
#for item in my_list:
for i in xrange(len(cleanlist)):
      # matching = [s for s in my_list if cleanlist[i] in s]
   # matching =  [x for x in my_list if cleanlist[i] in x]
    matching = any( cleanlist[[i]] in item for item in my_list)

print(matching)
```

Sample of my_list is `['Carbon Monoxide (Blood)', 'Carbon Monoxide Poisoning', 'Carbonic anhydrase inhibitor administered']`

Sample of cleanlist is `[['Antibody', 'Cardiolipin'], ['Cardiomegaly'], ['Cardiomyopathy'], ['Cardiopulmonary', 'Resuscitation', '(CPR)'], ['Diet', 'Cardiovascular'], ['Disease', 'Cardiovascular']]`

SOLVED[Now I'm having problems, My cleanlist is not containing only one item for each index, which makes the compare for matching hard, how to fix that??]

????Also, I want to create a list for each time of comparing, so for each comparing of the clean list, I want to create one list which will have the similar words between them,,, any help with that please??

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie of machine-learning, but maybe I can give you some advise.
let's suppose we have one row:

```
rowText = "mary have a little lamb"
```

then split the word and put it in a set:

```
MySet = set(rowText.split(' '))
```

now we can add more row to this set, finally we got a big set including all words.

```
MySet.add(newRowText.split(' '))
```

now, we should remove some not so important words such as "a", "an", "is", "are",etc.

Convert the set back to list with order, check the length of the List. now we can create a N-Dimension space, for example, the total List is ["Mary", "has", "lamb", "happy"]. the row is "Mary has a little lamb", so we can convert the sentence to [1, 1, 1, 0].

Now you can do Cluster now. right?

If you found the "Mary" is very important, you can adjust the weight of Mary like [2,1,1,0].

The precess way you can refer from Bayes as my opinion.

Comment: what I want are not the similar words in meaning, I want the similar like the exact text, for example: we have three words in different three rows: Heart attack , Heart failure, Heart broken.. for example .. I want those rows to be in one cluster cause they have the common word " Heart

Answer (score 0):

Clustering text is hard, and most approaches do not work well. Clustering single words essentially requires a *lot* of background knowledge.

If you had longer text, you could measure similarity by the words they have in common.

But for single words, this approach does not work.

Consider:

- Apple
- Banana
- Orange
- Pear
- Pea

To a human who knows a lot, apple and pear are supposedly the two most similar. To a computer who has only these 3 to 6 bytes of string data, pear and pea are the most similar words.

You see: language is a lot about background knowledge and associations. A computer who cannot associate both "apple" and "pear" with "fruit growing on a tree, usually green outside and white inside, black seeds in the center and a stem on top, about the size of a palm usually" *cannot* recognize what these have in common, and thus cannot cluster them.

Comment: I understand, but what I want are not the similar words in meaning, I want the similar like the exact text, for example: we have three words in different three rows:  Heart attack ,  Heart failure, Heart broken.. for example .. I want those rows to be in one cluster cause they have the common word " Heart".

Comment: That is not really a clustering problem then. More of a `GROUP BY`. Just build a dictionary, word to rows containing the words. Then look at those that have more than one row.

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Answer (score 0):

For clustering you need some kind of distance measurement. I suggest using the Hamming Distance (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). I think it's common to use it to measure similarity between two words.

Edit:

for your examples this would mean

Heart attack
Heart failure => dist 7

Heart attack
Heart broken => dist 6

Heart failure
Heart broken => dist 7

Heart broken
Banana        => dist 12